# Binary trie lexicological successor algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tree, traversal, trie, inorder

I have binary trie (the nodes have values, but because it's a trie that doesn't matter for now) and I want to find the lexicological (by key, inorder) successor of given node. The node is implemented with parent, left and right pointers.

I think the core idea should be to return the left child if it's available, else return the right child, and when there is no children go back till there is right child, then return that child. But that obviously leads to cycle in any right child. I can't think of any way to differentiate already visited right children from the ones yet to be visited. Something along the idea of "but when returning up go past some branching" maybe.

EDIT:

For example let's say the trie is (the chars are values here):

```
      A
     / \
    B   C
   / \   \
  D   E   F
```

Where every left child has key "0" and every right child has key "1". So when I want to access D, I will acces it with key "00".

Now I want the ordered output to be:

```
A with key ("")
B with key ("0")
D with key ("00")
E with key ("01")
C with key ("1")
F with key ("11")
```

Achieved with calling successorNode function until there is no successor.

EDIT 2

Sorry for possible misunderstanding - I need successor function, so the output will for example be:

```
input node* with value A with key ("") -> output node* B with key ("0")
input node* with value B with key ("0") -> output node* D with key ("00")
input node* with value D with key ("00") -> output node* E with key ("01")
input node* with value E with key ("01") -> output node* C with key ("1")
input node* with value C with key ("1") -> output node* F with key ("11")
```

Here is the iterator code (not working, I will add more later
):

```
 struct TrieIterator {
    TrieIterator() = default;
    TrieIterator(Node *current) : current(current) {}

    TrieIterator const& operator++() {
        inorderAdvance();
        return *this;
    }

    TrieIterator operator++(int) {
        auto copy = *this;
        inorderAdvance();
        return copy;
    }

    bool operator==(const TrieIterator& other) const {
        return current == other.current;
    }

    bool operator!=(const TrieIterator& other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    Node const& operator*() const {
        return *current;
    }

    Node& operator*() {
        return *current;
    }

    Node* operator->() const {
        return current;
    }

    Node* operator->() {
        return current;
    }
private:
    Node* current;
    Node* last;
    void inorderAdvance() {
        if (current->isLeaf() && (current->parent()->right() == current)) {
            current = nullptr;
            return; 
        }
        if (!current) {
            return;
        }
        if (current->left()) {
            current->left_.get();
            return;
        }
        if (current->right()) {
            current->right_.get();
        }
        while (!current->right()) {
            if(!current) {
                return;
            }
            current = current->parent_;
        }
        current->right_.get();
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you paste an example and desired output as well ? It will be easier to look into this problem then

Comment: Ohk So basically my input will be 00, so output should be D and if my input is 11 output should be F.. .something like this right ?

Comment: Am I right @Davar

Comment: Ohh my bad basically u want the output in that ordered which u have provided ... got it

Comment: have a look, I posted an answer

Comment: If all you need is an iterator, then do the depth-first search using an explicit stack that you maintain across calls to `next`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple and elegant solution for this problem which can be done in one traversal over this trie.

So let's start with root. Now because this trie is like a binary tree, we have conditions defined that if we take left, it's 0 otherwise it's 1.

Now I will keep track of a global HashMap with key as String and value also as String.

So for example key will be `00` and value will be `A`

Now let's take a look at pseudo code.

```
class Node {
  string value;
  Node left;
  Node right;
}

map<string, string> m; // This is global map

void traversal(Node root, string value) {
   if(root == NULL) {
      return;
   }
   m.insert(value, root.value);
   traversal(root->left, value + '0');
   traversal(root->right, value + '1');
}

sort(m.begin(), m.end());
```

so inside of your main() method you will be making a call as

```
traversal(root, "");
```

Now the map store key value pairs as following:-

```
""   -> A
"0"  -> B
"00" -> D
"01" -> E
"11" -> F
"1"  -> C
```

Now when you sort, it will arrange in the order, in which u want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is indeed a good solution for getting the output, but I think I wasn't specific enough (sorry) - I need successor function which takes node and outputs the next node. The reason for this is that I'm writing iterator for trie class and I need operator++.

Comment: So that part is pretty simple I guess right, you keep two pointers one to left and one to right and based on 0 or 1 you can return the address of either left or right respectively.

Comment: @Davar can you paste your code, which you are working on that way I can take a look and try my hands on it.

Comment: This is actually pretty minor problem in the assignment (I have working recursive traversal, I would just like iterators way more, because they would simplify the code a lot) - I have deadline in 3 hours, so then I hopefuly came back  and post...not the whole code (the faculty would be really mad for leaking it) but at least a working version of the trie.